# What is the Fb.ui feed picture size limits?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-feed

I'm using the [Fb.ui feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and I'm trying to find the picture size limits/requirements. Not all of my images appear using the feed, and I'd like to know exactly what the image requirements are. This is not well documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the [open graph image rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) apply:

> An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The
>   image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of
>   3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple
>   og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.

What is the size of the image you are unable to post?

Comment: 200x200 -> it is downsized to 90x90

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, the max size is 320x320.  It'll keep your aspect ratio within those bounds.

Comment: Hey can you mention how you are doing this?

Comment: If I remember, I made two example images, one a super tall portrait and the other a super wide landscape and then just saw what FB did.